# How To Get Ubuntu To Recognize Nvidia GTX 860M Graphics Card

Tags: nvidia

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 16.10 and my laptop has both an Intel GPU and Nvidia GTX 860M.

I know Ubuntu 15.10 recognized my card because I was creating images using the Processing application with image dimensions > 10K. Now I get an error saying the card is limited to 8192 as a max dimension.

Running the command **lspci**  I get the following relevant output:

> 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core
>   Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
>
> 01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 860M]
>   (rev a2)

Running the command **glxinfo**, I get the following relevant output:

> Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
>       Vendor: Intel Open Source Technology Center (0x8086)
>       Device: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Mobile  (0x416) OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center OpenGL renderer string:
>   Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Mobile

When I run the command **nvidia-settings** I get the following text output:

> ** (nvidia-settings:3831): WARNING **: PRIME: Failed to execute child process "/usr/bin/prime-supported" (No such file or directory)
>   ** Message: PRIME: is it supported? no
>
> ERROR: nvidia-settings could not find the registry key file. This file
>          should have been installed along with this driver at
>          /usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-key-documentation. The
>          application profiles will continue to work, but values cannot be
>          prepopulated or validated, and will not be listed in the help text.
>          Please see the README for possible values and descriptions. (nvidia-settings:3831): Gtk-CRITICAL **:
>   gtk_widget_get_preferred_width_for_height: assertion 'height >= 0'
>   failed (nvidia-settings:3831): Gtk-WARNING **:
>   gtk_widget_size_allocate(): attempt to allocate widget with width 10
>   and height -5 (nvidia-settings:3831): Gtk-CRITICAL **:
>   gtk_widget_get_preferred_width_for_height: assertion 'height >= 0'
>   failed (nvidia-settings:3831): Gtk-WARNING **:
>   gtk_widget_size_allocate(): attempt to allocate widget with width 10
>   and height -5 (nvidia-settings:3831): Gtk-CRITICAL **:
>   gtk_widget_get_preferred_width_for_height: assertion 'height >= 0'
>   failed (nvidia-settings:3831): Gtk-WARNING **:
>   gtk_widget_size_allocate(): attempt to allocate widget with width 10
>   and height -5 (nvidia-settings:3831): Gtk-CRITICAL **:
>   gtk_widget_get_preferred_width_for_height: assertion 'height >= 0'
>   failed (nvidia-settings:3831): Gtk-WARNING **:
>   gtk_widget_size_allocate(): attempt to allocate widget with width 10
>   and height -5 (nvidia-settings:3831): Gtk-CRITICAL **:
>   gtk_widget_get_preferred_width_for_height: assertion 'height >= 0'
>   failed (nvidia-settings:3831): Gtk-WARNING **:
>   gtk_widget_size_allocate(): attempt to allocate widget with width 10
>   and height -2

Addition: Here is the output of command: **lshw -C display**

```
 *-display UNCLAIMED
       description: 3D controller
       product: GM107M [GeForce GTX 860M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:f7000000-f707ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:29 memory:f7400000-f77fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:f000(size=64)
```

Lastly, here is a screenshot of the NVIDIA app:
[nvidia app screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WG8lf.jpg)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Question: In response to the lshw command, why is the entry associated with the NVIDIA card listed as display UNCLAIMED?

Comment: I got the same problem with same graphic card for Ubuntu 16.04. How did u solve it?

Answer (score 0):

In practice there is a bad idea to update ubuntu along different versions. I recommend you to look in the dash for the application "aditional drivers" and see if you have your nvidia drivers up to date (use the privative, tested one) and install (or reinstall the driver).

If that does not work I suggest you to do a clean install.

Comment: In the Additional Drivers tab, the following is listed
NVIDIA Corporation: GM107M (GeForce GTX 860M)
  This device is using an alternative driver.
  * Using X.Org X Server -- Nouveau display driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouveau (open source)

Unknown: Unknown
  This device is using an alternative driver.
  * Using Processor microcode firmware for Intel CPUs from intel-microcode(proprietary)

In the NVIDIA section, there are two NVIDIA drivers listed but not selected - they are NVIDIA binary drivers versions 361.42 and 340.96

Comment: The 361.42 version says anything about being proprietary or tested?

Comment: 361.42 does say proprietary, tested.  But I don't know if its that simple. One place says to run lsmod and look for either nvidia or nouveau in the output - that one or the other should be there. I have neither. I am also wondering why in response to lshw  -C display, nvidia is listed as display UNCLAIMED? I have no idea what is going on.   I must say this sort of stuff is making me question my decision to jump to Linux from WIndows.

Comment: Yeah this is a real problem when you update between major versions. It seems that you have no driver for your Nvidia card so I suggest you to install the 361.42 driver.

Comment: Why would I install 361.42 when the doc here 
https://launchpad.net/~graphics-drivers/+archive/ubuntu/ppa
gives the following as current status:
Current official release: `nvidia-370` (370.28)
Current long-lived branch release: `nvidia-367` (367.57)
For GeForce 8 and 9 series GPUs use `nvidia-340` (340.98)

Shouldn't I install 340.96?

Comment: Mmm that seems right, is the 340 proprietary and tested?

Comment: Wait a sec. Since NVIDIA is listed as using the XORG driver, shouldn't it be working? Why would using the XORG driver prevent my system from "seeing" the NVIDIA card? When I click on SYstem Settings - Details, it  shows my Intel GPU.  Also, lshw -C display shows NVIDIA under the heading " *-display UNCLAIMED". 

How do I know that this is a driver issue and not something else?

Comment: doing the ppa thing (as outlined here - http://www.webupd8.org/2016/06/how-to-install-latest-nvidia-drivers-in.html) I now have a much longer list of drivers showing up.  361.42 has now disappeared from the list but now a 361.45 shows up, as does a 340.98 - both of which are listed as open source.  Note that the proprietary and tested versions are now no longer listed.

Comment: I recommend you to install the proprietary, tested drivers. Get rid of that ppa

Comment: Your system is aware that you have a Nvidia card, it can "see" it but it is UNCLAIMED a.k.a unused and that could be because there is no driver to handle your card.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this. I'll have to get back to you tomorrow with an update.